# Replace a phone number using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, files, text-formatting

my txt file contains the phone number `(233)- 332-9888` and I want to replace that with `###-###-####`. 
I'm doing `s|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|###-###-####|g` (In extended mode), my issue is I don't know how where to match the parenthesis in the  first `[0-9]{3}`

Comment: I see a space between the first two sets of digits in the phone number, but not in your regular expression. Do you use GNU sed?

Comment: How do you invoke the Sed command? Why do you use {3} {3} {4} if the input phone number is in the form {3} {4} {4}?

Comment: @Quasímodo a phone format is xxx-xxx-xxxx not xxx-xxxx-xxxx

Comment: @seshoumara yeah the space was put there on purpose, I don't know to incorpote it to my script though, I use BSD

Comment: @kevo Yes, but the format of the input phone (233)- 3432-9888 is (xxx)- xxxx-xxxx, not xxx-xxx-xxxx. You should match the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's|\([0-9]{3}\)- [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}|###-###-####|g'
```

The parenthesis need to be escaped since they are treated specially in extended regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace the phone number with a standard 10-digit NANP-like  string, i.e. ###-###-####:

```
$ echo "(123) -456-7890" | sed 's/(\([0-9]\{3\}\)) -\([0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)/###-###-####/g'
###-###-####
```

If you want to reformat the phone number to match 10-digit NANP format:

```
$ echo "(123) -456-7890" | sed 's/(\([0-9]\{3\}\)) -\([0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)/\1-\2/g' 
123-456-7890
```

Comment: The OP wants to replace/hide the phone number, not to display it.